# Enable Ethernet tethering with LibreELEC

Tags: ethernet, connection, libreelec

I have my Raspberry Pi 3 connected to my WLAN with the on-board chip. Now I want to connect my TV's Ethernet cable (it does not have WiFi) to the RPi3 to connect to the Internet from my TV (Ethernet tethering).

Enabling Ethernet tethering with LibreELEC should be very straight forward with `connmanctl`:

```
connmanctl enable ethernet
connmanctl tether ethernet on
```

However the last command fails as Ethernet tethering cannot be enabled.

The problem is that I cannot add `ethernet` to the list of tethering technologies in `/etc/connman/main.conf`:

```
TetheringTechnologies = wifi,ethernet
```

This is because the file is read-only.

How can I enable Ethernet tethering then?

Comment: If someone could add the LibreELEC tag, that would be great. I do not have enough reputation to create a new tag, so I used the `openelec` tag instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternative that does not require editing the `/etc/connman/main.conf` file. Simply create a `/storage/.config/connman_main.conf` file and LibreELEC will load this configuration.

Start with a copy of the current configuration:

```
cp /etc/connman/main.conf /storage/.config/connman_main.conf
```

Now edit the new file and add `ethernet` to the list of tethering technologies:

```
[...]
TetheringTechnologies = wifi,ethernet
[...]
```

**Reboot**.

At this point you should be able to:

```
connmanctl enable ethernet
connmanctl tether ethernet on
```